# Can I make multiple separate profiles in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

So I was playing as a Khajiit, and I want to try being an Orc. Can I make a separate game file without deleting the original profile. I know it is possible on different games like Saints Row, but is it possible in Skyrim on PS3? THX!

Comment: I would think so? Unless it's different between Xbox and PlayStation, you should be able to just go back to the main menu and select "New Game". The only thing you will need to manage is your saves. Auto Saves will be over-written, but if you save manually, you can have as many characters as your harddrive has room for!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have multiple profiles on the one system. As Ben has stated, simply select **new game** from the main menu, create your new character and once you have finished save the game. When you wish to save **be sure to select new save** because if you just select another save that is already present, it will overwrite your previous characters save game. Also try not to have too many save files for each character as it can get confusing trying to find a file if you have multiple characters on the go!

Comment: But you should try to keep a rotation of 3-4 saves for each character as a safegaurd against game-ending bugs and file corruption.